GMW vs BGW: difference and application
What's the difference between GMW protocol and BGW protocol? For arithmetic circuits, how to choose them?

GMW Protocol
GMW (Goldreich-Micali-Wigderson) is very useful secret sharing based protocol that allows both Boolean and arithmetic circuit operations. The idea is,
each parties' private inputs are shared via additive secret sharing scheme to all parties. Then, calculation of objective functionality is done locally by them. At the end, parties' outputs are used to reconstruction of actual output of functionality.
Due to the linearity of XOR and NOT gates, there is no need to communication between parties for evaluation of these gates. However, same thing cannot be said for AND gate and interaction between parties is needed. At this point, Oblivious Transfer is applied to prevent the violation of privacy.
Unlike Yao's Protocol, GMW cannot be processed in one time settings. Only AND gates that are placed in same layer of the circuit can be evaluated in parallel. To reach next level, all computation at the previous round must be terminated. Since interaction between parties is needed for AND gate, round complexity of protocol is proportional to circuit depth which is the maximum number of AND gates on the line from beginning to end of the circuit.
BGW Protocol
BGW (Ben-Or-Goldwasser-Wigderson) is well known protocol that is operated on arithmetic circuits. As generic multiparty settings, underlying idea is same as the GMW's. Input values are shared among parties and evaluation is processed  locally.
As important distinction, BGW uses Shamir's Secret Sharing Scheme. Polynomials are used in the computation of circuit. Parties choose random polynomial with degree $t$ and constant term $x_{i}$ then share the points on the  polynomial with other parties such that $t+1$ points are required to construct secret input. Any subset of parties less than $t+1$ cannot obtain any information about shares. After sharing process, evaluation is done with addition, multiplication with constant and multiplication gates corresponding to parties' shares.
As in GMW Protocol, underlying secret sharing scheme is linear. So, linear operations that has applied on shared secrets don't prevent reconstruction of output in same manner. In this case, addition and multiplication with constant gates is not violate the linearity property. However, multiplication does not fit this case and it is required interaction between the parties.
Complexity Analysis
For BGW, communication complexity is quadratic function of number of parties and also linear with number of gates. However, total computational complexity is dominated by circuit evaluation phase. On the other hand, round complexity in this setting is linearly dependent to circuit depth. Since each multiplication gate requires communication, one round communication is needed for every layer of circuit due to the necessity of topological order.
Round complexity of GMW has same approachs with BGW. Since every AND gates requires interaction between parties, round complexity of the protocol is linearly dependent to circuit depth. However, for GMW protocol, requirement of Oblivious Transfer operation dominates the communication and computation complexity since it requires public key cryptography. Every party needs to apply $(A * (n^2-n)/2)$ 1-out-of-4 Oblivious Transfer operations where $A$ represents number of AND gates in the circuit.
Security Considerations
In a general sense, more secure protocols require more rounds, communication bits and computationally expensive operations. Clearly, the efficiency of protocol dramatically decreases by demanding active security.
Actually, there is no theoretical boundary to obtaining active security in general. The concept of GMW compiler states that any protocol that is based on semi-honest security can be converted to an actively secure protocol. However, it requires a large amount of complexity to provide Zero Knowledge proof for every step of the protocol. On the other hand, BGW protocol can be made actively secure by using verifiable secret sharing as an underlying scheme which also brings quadratically higher communication complexity.
From this point of view, feasibility of these models are:
BGW :
The BGW protocol achieves $n/2 > t$ with fairness and guaranteed
output delivery in semi-honest adversary model and $n/3 > t$ with fairness and guaranteed output delivery in malicious adversary model where $t$ is number of corrupted parties. BGW protocol also provides perfect security in these settings.
GMW : The GMW protocol achieves (n−1)-security based on (semi-honest)
oblivious transfer in semi-honest adversary model. The GMW protocol can be extended to the malicious setting by additionally relying on zero-knowledge proofs, where it achieves security-with-abort for t < n corrupted parties. On the other hand, GMW doesn't provide perfect secrecy. Security of GMW is statistical.

Thanks for answering! I'm also curious if GMW is better than BGW in any aspect.

It provides better security in terms of number of corrupted parties. You can also look at http://library.usc.edu.ph/ACM/SIGSAC%202017/ccs/p578.pdf

Oh I see. Thank you so much!

You are welcome, you can also thank with upvote if my answer is useful for you.

I really want to, but it seems that 15 reputation is needed. I will come back to upvote for you after it is reached.

Oh now I have 15 reputation, and thank you with a upvote!
